# Set default page zoom level in Epiphany (GNOME Web browser)

Tags: zooming, epiphany

I have a small screen with my laptop. In Firefox, I change the default page zoom level using the [NoSquint](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/nosquint/) extension, but I'm a Gnome user and I would prefer using Epiphany (Web)...

Is it possible to set a default page zoom level in Epiphany browser (Web) ?

I use Epiphany (Web) 3.6 on Ubuntu Gnome Remix 12.10.

Thanks,

Rémi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the dconf editor. I have issues with High DPI and needed the default zoom at 75%. In the dconf editor go to org/gnome/epiphany/web/default-zoom-level. A value of 1.0 is 100%, and you can do the math to get what you need.

[image]

Comment: 6 years later ;-) Seems like the option has been added in the meantime ! Thanks you !

Answer (score 1):

Im using Epiphany on a Raspberry Pi. From the browser, I selected *Settings → Preferences → Fonts and Style → Use Custom Stylesheet*, and then wrote a stylesheet (which needs to be at `/home/pi/.config/epiphany`) to change the size of the text. However, this is not ideal because the CSS settings can be over-ridden by the pages visited. As I’m new to this, I’ve yet to discover where the *Use Custom Stylesheet* setting is actually stored.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want text zoom then press CTRL and + sign.
If you want full page zoom, then check out this solution here:
http://gitorious.org/epiphany-fullzoom

Comment: Sorry but Ctrl+ produces a page zoom, not a text zoom. My issue is that I don't want to do it for every website I see, so I need a way to tell epiphany That I want every page to be 120 % larger for example. epiphany-fullzoom extension seems to have never started, files are almost empty. Thank you for your answer anyway !